# External database t implement tree like / hash map structure

Tags: java, database, hashmap, tree-structure

What external database can I use to work with my java application except Microsoft Access? I need a tree like structure or a hashmap and not relational tables.

Comment: What is your findings ??

Comment: XML is generally well-suited to tree-like structures

Comment: @wakjah OP asking about data bases

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For HashMap like i.e. Key,Value pair -> [`MongoDB`](http://www.mongodb.org/) would be a good choice since you store documents in it in BSON (Binary JSON) structure.

For Tree/Graph like structures -> [`Neo4j`](http://www.neo4j.org/) would be a good choice I guess.

Answer (score 1):

Well, relational tables can be used to do what a tree or a hashmap does, very easily. So something like MySQL or PostgreSQL could easily meet your needs.

If you really want a treelike/hashmap-like database, look at MapDB. It's very fast, and provides both trees and hashmaps.